# Java two level generics strange behaviour

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

I have the following logic

```
public class Why {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gen<A> gen = new Gen<>();
        gen.m(new A()); //eeeeeeeeee A
    }
}

class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

class Gen<E> {
    Test test = new Test();

    public void m(E e) {
        test.test(e);
    }
}

class Test {

    public <E extends A> void test(E e) {
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXX " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    public <E> void test(E e) {
        System.out.println("eeeeeeeeee " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

the output for main means the compiler picks the second method in Test, is it strange or I missed something? shouldn'd java know the actual class for Gen#test?

Comment: Shouldn't this be obvious ? What happens when you pass `gen.m(new B())` . Let me know which method is called.

Comment: At `public void m(E e) { test.test(e); }` `E` comes from `class Gen<E>` but at that point it is not known so compiler must select method signature which will match *any* type which can be assigned to E, which here is `public <E> void test(E e) {..}` not `public <E extends A> void test(E e) {..}`. If you want to let compiler know that E may *only* accept subclasses of A so it could be handled by `public <E extends A> void test(E e) {..}` declare it as `class Gen<E extends  A> {..}`.

Comment: for ```gen.m(new B())``` it is returning the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method overload resolution happens at compile-time.

When the compiler is compiling `Gen<E>`, it doesn't know anything about `E`, i.e. it cannot guarantee that `E` extends `A`, so it has to call the overload of `test` with `<E>`.

If you remove that overload of `test()`, you'll get a compile error, since the other one is not compatible at all:
   `The method test(E extends A) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (E)`

To make it call the other one, change to `Gen<E extends A>`.